# Why does the Call Stack window in VS2017 show less entries than in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2017, callstack

The call stack window in VS2017 doesn't show the startup external code entries where VS2012 did.

I have attached a couple of screen shots to show what I am talking about.

[image: Call Stack window in VS2012]

[image: Call Stack window in VS2017]

NOTE:  Just My Code is off already as I am playing with symbols so this is not the issue.

I wondered if anyone knew why?  It's not a big issue.  I'm just curious about the whys.

I noticed it when I was playing with loading external symbols.  One article said that you could load symbols from the Call Stack window by right-clicking an external code entry.  However, I couldn't do this in VS 2017 because the entries were missing.

However, after I loaded symbols (via the Modules window from a dotPeek symbol server) I could then view external code entries.

[image: External code entries visible after symbols loaded]

Comment: Disable Just My Code.

Comment: @SLaks:  Thanks for your reply.  However, as I mention in my question I am playing with symbols.  This requires Just My Code to be off.  I will add this information to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Visual Studio hosting process option was discontinued in VS2017.  So you will never see it back in the stack trace anymore.  It won't be missed.

Note that it was already an option in previous VS versions: Project > Properties > Debug tab.  VS project templates shipped with the option turned on by default.

Comment: Thank you!  I turned it off in my VS2012 test and the extra entries vanished.  That explains it completely.